# Enumerate with Properties

Tags: lists, enumerate

How can I easily customize the `\enumerate` environment so that, instead of each line being numbered `1.`, `2.`, etc., they are numbered `Property 1.`, `Property 2.`, etc.?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use for example the `enumitem` package to customize the `enumerate` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=Property \arabic*.,itemindent=*]
  \item First
  \item Second
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

`enumitem` also allows you to define your own list environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{Properties}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[Properties]{label=Property \arabic*.,itemindent=*}
\begin{document}
\begin{Properties}
  \item First
  \item Second
\end{Properties}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Setting the `itemindent` to `*` automatically calculates the necessary width for the entire label. Without this the label will run into the left margin.

If an item text is too long to fit on one line, the next line will be indented a little from the left margin:

[image]

If you want this second line to be aligned with the start of the item text, use `leftmargin=*` instead of `itemindent=*`. If you want the second line to not be indented, use `leftmargin=0pt` in addition to `itemindent=*`. The following example sums this up:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
Just changing the label:
\begin{enumerate}[label=Property \arabic*.]
  \item First, with a very long text that should extend to the next line if I'm not very  much mistaken. 
  \item Second. 
\end{enumerate}

\hrule\medskip

With \verb|itemindent=*|:
\begin{enumerate}[label=Property \arabic*.,itemindent=*]
  \item First, with a very long text that should extend to the next line if I'm not very  much mistaken. 
  \item Second. 
\end{enumerate}

\hrule\medskip

With \verb|leftmargin=*|:
\begin{enumerate}[label=Property \arabic*.,leftmargin=*]
  \item First, with a very long text that should extend to the next line if I'm not very  much mistaken. 
  \item Second. 
\end{enumerate}

\hrule\medskip

With \verb|itemindent=*,leftmargin=0pt|:
\begin{enumerate}[label=Property \arabic*.,itemindent=*,leftmargin=0pt]
  \item First, with a very long text that should extend to the next line if I'm not very  much mistaken. 
  \item Second. 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could change the value for `leftmargin`?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Good point, I didn't realize or notice that it would extend into the margin.

Comment: Yes, how would you correct that `leftmargin` parameter so it doesn't extend into the margins?

Comment: `leftmargin=*` does it

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks, I should have checked the manual. `*` is a little more convenient.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., if the item is too long and has more than one line, how to make the second line starts at the left margin?

Comment: @Sigur `itemindent=*,leftmargin=0pt`, see my edited answer.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., perfect!! Thanks so much for your effort.