# difficulty using \newcommand with previously specified new commands

Tags: macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Definining commands/abbreviations that contain numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9718/definining-commands-abbreviations-that-contain-numbers)

I'm having some difficulty with setting a command using `\newcommand`. The command I'm trying to create is as follows:

```
\newcommand{
        checklist1Start
    }
    {
        \begin{description}[style=multiline,
            itemsep=\itemSeparationDistance,
            leftmargin=\leftMarginDistance,
            itemindent=\itemIndentDistance,
            labelindent=\labelIndentDistance,
            font=\normalfont]
    }
```

The distances shown are defined using other other uses of `\newcommand`, in the following manner:

```
\newcommand{\leftMarginDistance}{9 cm}
```

The error returned on attempting to compile is as follows:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero
```

Could you point me in the right direction on using `\newcommand` properly here?

Many preemptive thanks for any assistance

Comment: Basically, you can't (or at least shouldn't) define commands whose name contains numbers. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9718/definining-commands-abbreviations-that-contain-numbers

Comment: Since those "inner commands" are in fact lengths, why dont you define them as lengths? E.g. `\newlength\leftMarginDistance` and `\setlength\leftMarginDistance{9cm}`

Comment: Are you using `enumitem`? Why not create a new custom list type? A simple example is found in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37740/enumerate-with-properties/37741#37741

Comment: @lockstep, true, but that is not the case here.

Comment: @JLDiaz Seems like "checklist1Start" to me. (I didn't spot it instantly, too.)

Comment: Ah, yes! And it lacks the leading `\` too

Answer (score 12):

The token in the first argument of  `\newcommand` has to be a single token such as `\zzzz` not a sequence of white space, letters and numbers. You get the same error message for *any* definition you make in the second argument. You get exactly the same error for

```
 \newcommand{ checklist1Start }{}
```

Comment: Specifically, the token must include the leading backslash.  Bites me every time.