# Enumerate numbering is out of page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, enumerate

I have nested enumerations in my article. The numbering of enumeration is modified.

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\bfseries\thesubsection.\arabic{enumi}} 
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\bfseries\thesubsection.\arabic{enumi}.%
                            \arabic{enumii}} 
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\bfseries\thesubsection.\arabic{enumi}.%
                             \arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}} 
\renewcommand{\labelenumiv}{\bfseries\thesubsection.\arabic{enumi}.%
                            \arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}.%
                            \arabic{enumiv}}
```

The numbers of my items are out of page. How to align them properly?

I saw [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29322/how-to-make-enumerate-items-align-at-left-margin). Did not help.

**UPDATE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec} % loaded by polyglossia, but included here for transparency

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\def\do{}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{Consolas}
\def\do{}
%\usepackage{algorithm}

%\setmainlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{Consolas}


\usepackage[hmargin=0.1cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.2cm}   %The is a way to define the distance between the two columns, use
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}  %If you need a line to separate the columns, the following command will do the job:

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
\fancyhead[L]{\DocumentTitle}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{\DocumentTitle}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}


\newcommand{\DocumentTitle}{Scientific Computing 1}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\bfseries\thesubsection.\arabic{enumi}} 
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\bfseries\thesubsection.\arabic{enumi}.%
                            \arabic{enumii}} 
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\bfseries\thesubsection.\arabic{enumi}.%
                             \arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}} 
\renewcommand{\labelenumiv}{\bfseries\thesubsection.\arabic{enumi}.%
                            \arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}.%
                            \arabic{enumiv}}

\begin{document}
\raggedbottom

\section{Direction Fields} % (fold)

\section{Critical Points}

\section{Population Models}
\subsection{Model of Malthus}
\subsection{Model of Verhulst - Saturation}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item 1 
    \item Item 2 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[MWE](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B9TsO3R5JYQjVDVIUzVyZlQ0Nms)

Comment: Still, the post you cited should contain the solution to your problem. Could you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates what goes wrong? Also related: [Enumerate with Properties](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37740/12850).

Comment: You can adjust the value for the length `\leftmargini`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to adjust the value for the `\leftmargini` length (in my example code I removed some packages that were not relevant for the problem and its solution):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.1cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.2cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\bfseries\thesubsection.\arabic{enumi}} 
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\bfseries\thesubsection.\arabic{enumi}.%
                            \arabic{enumii}} 
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\bfseries\thesubsection.\arabic{enumi}.%
                             \arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}} 
\renewcommand{\labelenumiv}{\bfseries\thesubsection.\arabic{enumi}.%
                            \arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}.%
                            \arabic{enumiv}}

\begin{document}
\raggedbottom

\section{Direction Fields} % (fold)

\section{Critical Points}

\section{Population Models}
\subsection{Model of Malthus}
\subsection{Model of Verhulst - Saturation}

\addtolength\leftmargini{9pt}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item 1 
    \item Item 2 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the above approach, probably you will also have to adjust `\leftmarginii`, etc. Another option is to use the `enumitem` package to do the job (no need for manual adjustments), since you are already loading it (notice also that the customization of the labels is much simpler using the package):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.1cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlength{\columnsep}{0.2cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\bfseries\thesubsection.\arabic*}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label*=\bfseries.\arabic*} 
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label*=\bfseries.\arabic*} 
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label*=\bfseries.\arabic*}
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}
\raggedbottom

\section{Direction Fields} % (fold)

\section{Critical Points}

\section{Population Models}
\subsection{Model of Malthus}
\subsection{Model of Verhulst - Saturation}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item 1 
    \item Item 2 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]