# How to create a list with a fixed prefix and incremental numbers

Tags: lists, enumerate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enumerate with Properties](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37740/enumerate-with-properties)

How can I create a list with a mixed listing, i.e. made of a fixed prefix (e.g. a letter) and an auto incremented number. E.g.

```
A1 my text....
A2 another text;
A3 again text.
```

Maybe exists such a package that I don't know...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=A\arabic*]
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to install the package! Just let me a few minutes to check it out!

Comment: It works as promised :). And I see that I can also specify italics and bold styles. Very nice package! Thanks again!

Comment: What does the `*` in `\arabic*` do?

Comment: @MartinThoma According to the [documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf), "A set of starred versions of \alph, \Alph, \arabic, \roman and \Roman, without argument stand for the current counter in enumerate". I.e. it is required to ensure that the current number is print.

Comment: I had to add the `leftmargin=*` to the options so that it is aligned on the left correctly.
Full command: `\begin{enumerate}[label=Stufe \arabic*:, leftmargin=*]`