# enumerate with section index as prefix

Tags: enumitem

I want to create a numbered list, where each item number is prefixed by the section number. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94225/178369) shows how to make customized prefixes using the `enumitem` package. But the problem is I have to hard code the section number. Is there a way to populate the section number automatically?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,label=Q1.1.\arabic*]
\item First question
\item Second question
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try `label=\thesection.\arabic*`?

Comment: Perfect! I used `label=\textbf{\thesubsection.\arabic*}` to get the subsection number as well. If you write this as an answer, I will accept it

Comment: Thank you. I don't think it's necessary , as I'm pretty sure there already exists such an answer (albeit I don't know where, exactly).

Comment: Should add \protect before label.

Comment: What will that do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bernand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard)'s suggestion worked. Below is the complete code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,label=\thesubsection.\arabic*]
\item First question
\item Second question
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A global setting is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\thesection.\theenumi)} %i,ii,iii,...

\title{A Test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
    \section{Enumeration Numbers}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First question
        \item Second question
    \end{enumerate}
    
\end{document}
```

And the output is

[image]