# How to combine label and counter in enumerate?

Tags: lists, enumerate

Essentially, I would like the following:

```
X1. text text text 
X2. text2 text2 text2
X3. text text textaaa
```

So, talking code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item text text text 
    \item text2 text2 text2
    \item text text textaaa
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37740/enumerate-with-properties/37741#37741 helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are fancier newer packages (eg `enumitem`) but the core latex distribution has an `enumerate` package that lets you do:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[X1.]
    \item text text text 
    \item text2 text2 text2
    \item text text textaaa
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I am trying it but I get "Latex Error: ./questions.tex:14 Package keyval Error: X1. undefined." Do you know what that is?

Comment: @user3232 `enumerate` doesn't use `keyval` did you use exactly as above or use `enumitem` which uses a keyval syntax.

Comment: I see that in my document I have got \usepackage{enumitem}. This fixed the problem: \begin{enumerate}[label=X\arabic*.,leftmargin=*]

Comment: How do I set custom number to begin, so let's say start with X4?

Comment: found it, start=4

Answer (score 5):

Without a package you can use

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{X\arabic{enumi}.}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item text text text 
    \item text2 text2 text2
    \item text text textaaa
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

but [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) is a great way to go

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=X\arabic*.}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item text text text 
    \item text2 text2 text2
    \item text text textaaa
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```