# Create a "case"-environment

Tags: environments, itemize

I'd like to create an environment for enumerating different cases.  Something that would look like `\itemize` but instead of printing a "-" symbol at the begining of each item, prints (for the first item) "Case 1:" (eventually in a big font) and then line breaks , "Case 2:" and then line breaks for the second item, etc.  Moreover I'd like not to have any margin after the break line, I'd like to have everything I write after "Case 1:" to begin at the same spot as the rest of my domcument.
I'd also like that the different cases can have "names", for example somthing like the `\theorem` environment where you can put the name of the author in brackets.
Is there any command that already does what I want? Otherwise can somebody help me to create such environment?

Edit:

Thanks a lot I managed to do something close to what I wanted but I still can't make Latex break line after "Case"...  This is what I wrote:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{cases}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[cases]{label=\textbf{Cas \arabic* :}, itemindent=*,leftmargin=0pt}
```

But when I try to add in the `setlist` argument `breakline` or `\\` I only get errors...
Also do you have any idea to add an argument to this new list so that it prints a title in backets and then break a line?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37740/enumerate-with-properties/37741#37741

Answer (score 2):

I fudged it with a `\trlap` from `stackengine` package.  EDITED to add `listparindent` specifier.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewlist{cases}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[cases]{label=%
  \trlap{\textbf{\kern5pt Cas \arabic* :}}, itemindent=0pt,leftmargin=0pt,
  listparindent=1.5em}
\begin{document}
\begin{cases}
\item \lipsum[1]

\lipsum[4]

\item \lipsum[4]
\end{cases}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What you've done is very close to what I wanted but I'd also like to have an indent Inside the "case" environement every time I skip a line in the source.

Comment: @WrabbitW  I added a `listparindent` specifier.  Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Hi, thanks for letting me know the `listparindent` command! I did not quite well get the effects of `trlap` and `kern5pt`...   Could you quickly explain it to me?

Comment: @WrabbitW  `\trlap` is a "top-right" lap, that is it adds a notation above and to the right of the current location.  The notation has height (so it won't overwrite what is above), but is perceived to have no width, so it doesn't move the current location to the right (see pp. 9, 15 of `stackengine` documentation, http://www.ctan.org/pkg/stackengine).  The `\kern` shifts the item left(-), right(+).  It should not have been needed, but for some reason, without it, it caused the header to not align.  So it's a "fix."

Comment: Thank's I'm a beginner in the Tex world so I don't get the subtilities of heigh and width but I'll get there!  I also wanted some cases to have a "title" that is on the same line as "Cas 1:" but written in italic. To do that I used te answer of SlX64 but if had an `itemize` environment inside the case environment I can't write anything after the "-", exept if I enter this line in the argument of the item but then it's in italic too...

Comment: @WrabbitW To this point, I haven't figured out how to add an additional optional label to the end of the (for example) "Cas 1:" line.  I'll keep thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need something like this?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}

 \newenvironment{case}{%
 \let\olditem\item% 
 \renewcommand\item[1][]{\olditem \textbf{##1} \\}%
 \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Case \arabic*:},itemindent=*,leftmargin=0em]}{\end{enumerate}%
 }

\begin{document}

\blindtext

 \begin{case}
  \item[Title of my first item] \blindtext
\end{case}

\blindtext 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes that's quite exactly what I wanted, exept that I'd like to break a line after "Title of my first item"... Moreover I's like to have an indent Inside the "case" environement every time I skip a line in the source.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, we are really close : I'll just add `listparindent=1.5em` in the arguments of the new `enumerate` environment to do exactly what I wanted!