# \begin{properties}: how to make " propertie " bold in latex

Tags: enumerate, enumitem, bold

To create a list of properties I am using an example from the [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37740/enumerate-with-properties).

```
\begin{Properties}
  \item First
  \item Second
\end{Properties}
```

The result:

[image]

I would like to make the texts "Property 1" "Property 2" bold. How to do it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, @AnnaKoroleva Could you please edit your question to provide a minimal working example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`? That would make it self-contained and more useful for everyone (no link to click before one can understand what you are talking about...). You can copy the code from the first answer in your link (keep the link too, it is good practice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. You can use `font=\textbf`. According to the `enumitem` documentation:

> `font=<commands>` `format=<commands>`
>
> Sets the label font. Useful when the label is changed with the optional argument of `\item` and in `description`. The last command in `<commands>` can take an argument with the item label. In `description`, class settings are in force, so you may want to begin with `\normalfont`. A synonymous is `format`. Actually, this key may be used for any stuff to be executed at each `\item`, just before the label.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% From <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37741/73317> (Torbjørn T.)
\newlist{Properties}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[Properties]{label=Property \arabic*., font=\textbf, itemindent=*}

\begin{document}

\begin{Properties}
  \item First
  \item Second
\end{Properties}

\end{document}
```

[image]